# D3.js stacked bar chart of array of object

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a stacked bar chart where x-axis is cat_desc and y-axis is met1 array objects. I have a working code here http://jsfiddle.net/aunbc2td/

But I am stuck at this :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y1' of undefined"
The issue seem to be in the code segment below: Any help?

```
data.cat[0].met1.forEach(function(d) {      
         var y0 = 0;     
         d.catDesc = color.domain().map(function(name) {  
      return {name: name, y0: y0/sum, y1: (y0 += +d[name])/sum }; });  
       d.total = d.catDesc[d.catDesc.length - 1].y1;   
    console.log(d.catDesc);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`color.domain()` is empty for ordinal scales until they're used.  So:

```
color.domain(); // will be []
color('one');
color('two');
color.domain(); // will be ['one', 'two']
```

And that's why your function's failing, `d.catDesc` will get set to `[]` and so `d.catDesc[d.catDesc.length - 1]` will be undefined, therefore it won't have a `y1`.  What helps here is just patience and stepping through this stuff slowly and understanding what you're writing.

Comment: Thanks @Milimetric but I am trying to figure it out!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be snarky, just mentioning that you should be patient with yourself and allow time to debug, it'll pay off :)

Comment: I have tried all methods I could, it seem I am getting something wrong. Please throw more light or refer. Thanks.